# Git How to avoid merge conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have `master` and `feature-1` branch on my git.

Now, I need to work on `feature-2` branch which is dependent on `feature-1`. I can't merge `feature-1` to `master` yet because of some dependency. So, I merged `feature-1` to `feature-2`.

Amid developing `feature-2`, I merged `feature-1` to `master`. Now, is there a way to merge `feature-2` back to `master` without merge conflicts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it.  You won't get merge conflicts.  Git will understand that the same commits exist on both branches.